# Python, How to fill up a column in an empty numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would normally go to

```
http://docs.scipy.org
```

for this info but their website is down for some reason:/

But how would I be able to fill up an entire column in a numpy matrix?

```
a = numpy.zeros(shape=(100,10))
a[0] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

fills up a row, but how can you do a column?

Comment: `a[:, k] = values`. You would have found that in any NumPy tutorial.

Comment: @larsmans that is definitely the answer.

Comment: @larsmans perhaps you can post your comment as the answer

Comment: @SaulloCastro You may post it if you want, I'm not interested in this basic stuff.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replacing numpy array values python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352778/replacing-numpy-array-values-python)

Answer (score 5):

Never too late to answer...

```
a[:, k] = values
```

Answer (score 1):

This fills the same value in all columns:

```
  array[:, column] = values
```

Comment: The question was how to fill up an entire column, not how to fill all columns with the same value.